# livereload only responding to css changes, not html

Tags: ruby, livereload

I have installed livereload gem, which I'm using with a ruby middleman application. However, it's only autoloading changes to the css. If I make changes to the html files, I still have to restart the server to view the changes. Is there somehow I can make it autoload html changes?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this feature doesn't work on all versions of livereload and also depends on the browser and it's extensions.  Try to also change a css file when you change the html so that the refresh occurs. Also, have you looked at https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload ? That has an example watching the change of html.

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
  # Rails Assets Pipeline
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|js|html))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end
```